# Why don't I have debug option under Tools in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008

I'm having an issue with a referenced dll in my application that I want to be able to step into through debugging and found out about the Just My Code option under the Debug option under Tools.  But when I load my tools I only have 5 options and Debug isn't one of them.

Enviornment
Projects and solutions
Text Editor
Windows Form Designer
Device Tools

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition, why wouldn't this be included in every version of VS2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, silly me.  There's a checkbox "Show all Settings" that will show the rest of the options that were hidden.